# Windows Store allow touch event to pass through a shape

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am writing a Windows Store (8.1) app which contains a web view.  The web view needs to be able to receive touch events.  On its own, this works fine (obviously).  However, there are times when I need to draw on top of the web view.  For this I am using Shapes (Polyline, Polygon, Ellipse etc).  However, once a shape is position over the web view, the shape eats all of the touch events that I would like to go to the web view.

Is there any way for UI elements in Windows Store to ignore touch events and allow them to pass to the elements they are covering?  Remember, the shapes are not a child of the WebView (a WebView cannot have children).

I have done a bunch of searching this morning and I cannot find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

More than one way.

```
<Rectangle IsHitTestVisible="False" />

<Rectangle ManipulationMode="None"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with items that are on top of a WebView unfortunately.